# why is curl waiting for a keypress?

Tags: php, bash, curl

I simply want to run the following command:

```
curl https://jkanime.net/um.php?e=VTJpeCsrL3BVY2xMaEd0YWhyM1k4SDdHelZ4OGZSeXFsOHBla1QrcnBPQm4wUWc1eE1TOThmWlBOb2xLOEJCeWlGenpML2tYelA3Tm8xU1lDMDRwUlE9PTo616MlXtdmRfi6FOwaoBRqeA--&t=5ec9cff996b02bf751b55c92c4cb1170
```

It seems to connect just fine, but it hangs waiting for a keypress. How can I automatize this in a script?

EDIT:
I have absolutely no idea but it solved by erasing the `--` part of the URL. Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: It's not the `--`, it's the `&`, which sends what comes before it to the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, you must use quotes (single or double, that depends what you want to do) to build one complete string by escaping some characters : ` $ ( ) [ ] { } & | *space*

So, use quotes around the URL:

```sh
curl --url 'https://jkanime.net/um.php?e=VTJpeCsrL3BVY2xMaEd0YWhyM1k4SDdHelZ4OGZSeXFsOHBla1QrcnBPQm4wUWc1eE1TOThmWlBOb2xLOEJCeWlGenpML2tYelA3Tm8xU1lDMDRwUlE9PTo616MlXtdmRfi6FOwaoBRqeA--&t=5ec9cff996b02bf751b55c92c4cb1170'
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't describe your environment, but it's probably your shell interpreting the unquoted hyphens. In bash, double hyphens terminate processing. If you surround your URL with quotes, it will avoid this behavior and pass the quoted string to curl.